# Design Decision - MassTransit or NetMQ

Tags: c#, design, architecture, .net, messaging

We work in a traveling company. 
We sell tickets for domestic flights, international flights, trains, and buses.

Currently, each of these products has its own team members and they use different libraries/tools to develop their product on their own. 
One team may use RabbitMQ as their message broker between its microservices and another team may use NetMQ and another team may use X and Y.

In one of our products, domestic flight, one of its team members has written a tool named **MQTools** which is a wrapper over [NetMQ](https://github.com/zeromq/netmq) messaging library that creates some functionalities over that like Service Discovery/Existence Broadcaster, Data Publisher/Data Subscriber, Work Distributor/Worker and so on.

This tool is used in the **domestic flight** team for about a year and it answers most of the domestic flight product needs.

There are multiple problems with **MQTools**:

1- It’s developed just by a single person, and today this person has left the company and we do not have access to him, so now **MQTools** is a semi **blackbox** tool for us. Although, I've said semi because it’s not a very big library and we can learn it on our own in about 2,3 weeks but it's a little hard work at least for the first weeks to add new features to that.

2- Another problem that we have with MQTools is that it doesn't have a very good code-base and a lot of code smells could be found in its source code.

3- It uses NetMQ as its underlying message library which it's not a popular and actively developing library on its own and there are no online tutorials/books about it and I think new members don’t like to work on a platform like this.

---

Now, all of these traveling products like flights, trains, and buses have exactly the same steps but one could have additional steps or the order of the steps could be different based on the product.

Our vision is that we can make an abstraction for these products, so the members of such teams can just write their logic code and so, they will not have any concern about the underlying messaging mechanisms and such stuff. They just have to override the defined steps and write their logic code.

With all of these stories, we can implement such a thing in two ways:

1- Using **MQTools** which is written specifically for *domestic flight* product, so it needs to be **refactored** first to remove its code smells and being fully **documented** so new members could be able to learn this tool easily.
Secondly, it should be **abstracted** in a way that all traveling products could use that because it's now developed with the domestic flight team in mind only.

2- Using a 3rd-party tool like [MassTransit](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit) to remove MQTools, because MQTools has tried to implement some functionalities on top of **NetMQ** which I think it’s like rewriting a tool like **MassTransit** which works like this on top of RabbitMQ, AmazonMQ, Azure-SB and so on.

MQTools is not exactly a message bus like MassTransit. It has been developed with some extra features than a *“message bus”* because it didn't have explicit boundaries and now by replacing that, some of those features need to be rewritten using MassTransit.

---

By using *MassTransit* instead of something like *MQTools* we will gain these **pros**:

1- We’ve removed a black box from our system called **MQTools**.

2- MassTransit with RabbitMQ has a lot easier learning curve than NetMQ and MQTools so new members have a lot more resources to learn this stack.

3- MassTransit is a stable library that has been there and developed since 2012 and it has been used in many projects.

4- With MassTransit, we don’t have to deal with low-level MQ concepts that exist in NetMQ like message-frames, beacons, pollers and so on.

5- We have some pre-built features like **monitoring solutions** on top of RabbitMQ such as [DataDog](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/rabbitmq-monitoring/) or [Prometheus/Grafana](https://www.rabbitmq.com/prometheus.html).

6- We're able to easily switch to other [transports](https://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/transports.html) like ActiveMQ, AmazonMQ and Azure Service Bus.

---

And here is *MassTransit* and *RabbitMQ* **cons**:

1- **RabbitMQ** is a **broker** and this broker could be a failure point, but **NetMQ** is **broker-less**.

2- Some of MQTools functionalities need to be rewritten with MassTransit according to replacement changes.

---

Now my question is which approach should I choose:

1- **Refactoring MQTools**, creating documentation for that and abstracting it in a way that can be used in different products.

2- **Replacing MQTools with MassTransit** and rewriting some of its missing features as an extension on top of MassTransit and abstracting it in a way that can be used in different products.

- It’s also worth mentioning that there’s nothing that could be implemented with NetMQ and cannot be implemented with MassTransit and visa-versa.

Comment: This is really a question you should be asking to your team and the people who have to deal with the consequences, risks, time and cost of whatever decision you make.     That should also idealy include whoever ultimately controls the decision on how much time and money to spend on whatever work you're going to do.     This is essentially an implementation decision, so there's not really much value in getting an answer from people who aren't close to your product and aren't somehow linked/invested/involved in your code.

Comment: Thanks, @BenCottrell. Actually, we don't have time and money limitations in this project cause we have a working version of all of these products so this is not a big concern for us and also, we don't want any risks in this project. The problem is that some agree with the first approach and others agree with the second one, and we cannot decide at this moment.